# How to run the VBA code while selecting an drop down menu item

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my MS Word form, there are some drop down menus. By default "Yes" is the green and "No" is the red in color while the file is opened. I would like to change the font color of the drop down menu items while selected, to be Red in case of "No" and to be Green in case of "Yes".

For this purpose I have created a `Document_ContentControlOnExit`sub currently only for the "Did the AA's performance drop after the incident? question in the following MS Word form. But the code is not running while selecting the "Yes" from the drop down menu. I can write and run VBA code in MS Excel but new to MS Word VBA, thus confused how to run the code. Can any one help?

I also would like to create a VBA code which will check and make sure that all "No" are Red and "Yes" are Green while the file is opened. So I think, there should be a VBA which will run during the MS Word file opening and iterate through all the Drop Down menus for that purposes. But this is secondary, if solved, bonus but not so important, at this moment it is important to me to change the font color during selecting menu items.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With ContentControl
    If .Title = "incident" Then
    Select Case .Range.Text
      Case "Yes": .Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
      Case "No": .Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
      Case Else: .Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdAuto
    End Select
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the MS Word file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Avjx8nubEIp9K9NwqtyfHvdohQEsQiP8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which module is your code in? `Document_ContentControlOnExit` is an event handler so it should be in the "ThisDocument" module.

Comment: Your code is not in the "ThisDocument" module. As Tmothy says, that is where it needs to be.

Comment: Thankyou. I have shifted the code to "ThisDocument" module and it works! If any of you (@TimothyRylatt or @macropod) answer my question, I can accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check which module your code is in.

`Document_ContentControlOnExit` is a document level event handler so it should be in the "ThisDocument" module.

Also note that in the tools area at the top of that module there are two drop down menus. These can be used to create event handlers for the document's objects and are useful to ensure that the syntax is correct.

[image]